# Setting max width to container

Tags: html, css

How can I configure my css to make sure that once the vertical length of the container exceeds say 375px, it automatically adds the images beside the first row?

Take a look at my DEMO below

**HTML**

```
<div class="panes">

<div id="one">
<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>

<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>

<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panes {
max-width:375px?
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to happen. What is the first row? Does "beside" mean on its right side, or below, or somewhere else?

Comment: You are able to set the width using css of the parent container (of the images) then when that length exceeds that width, then it wraps naturally..

Comment: okey could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the vertical length is given by the `height` attribute, not the `width`.

Second, you'll need some javascript to do what you want. Insert the image where you want it placed, and make its attribute `visibility = "hidden";`.

Then, use a javascript function on the load, or on the event that better suits your problem, so that this function resets the visibility of the image to `visibility = "visible"`.

You may use the javascript function to insert the element, instead of simply changing it's visibility.

Answer (score 1):

**float: left;**

http://jsfiddle.net/LTtEN/

Here you go:

```
<div class="panes">
<div class="test">
<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>
</div>

<div class="test">
<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>
</div>

<div class="test">
<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>
</div>

<div class="test">
<a href="#"><img src=".jpg" width=100 height=100 /></a>
<div>Caption</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panes {width:375px}
.test {float: left; width: 100px; padding: 6px;}
```

Comment: you mean to tell me this is not working? How are you adding the css? you dont need js for this..I added JSFiddler for you...

Comment: You have not understood my question, I am sorry. I want the images to be displayed inline by default and once 3 images are in one line, the fourth should jump to the next column and lay out another 3 images... your markup and css does not do that. Far from it.